# Combine multiple grep variables in one column-wise file

Tags: bash, count, grep

I have some grep expressions which count the number of lines matching a string, each one for a group of files with different extension:

```
Nreads_ini=$(grep -c '^>' $WDIR/*_R1.trim.contigs.fasta)
Nreads_align=$(grep -c '^>' $WDIR/*_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align)
Nreads_preclust=$(grep -c '^>' $WDIR/*_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.filter.unique.precluster.fasta)
Nreads_final=$(grep -c '^>' $WDIR/*_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.filter.unique.precluster.pick.fasta)
```

Each of these greps outputs the sample name and the number of occurences, as follows.

The first one:

```
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A1_bach1_GTATCGTCGT_R1.trim.contigs.fasta:13175
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A2_bach2_GAGTGATCGT_R1.trim.contigs.fasta:14801
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A3_bach3_TGAGCGTGCT_R1.trim.contigs.fasta:13475
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A4_bach4_TGTGTGCATG_R1.trim.contigs.fasta:13424
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A5_bach5_TGTGCTCGCA_R1.trim.contigs.fasta:12053
```

The second one:

```
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A1_bach1_GTATCGTCGT_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:12589
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A2_bach2_GAGTGATCGT_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:13934
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A3_bach3_TGAGCGTGCT_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:12981
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A4_bach4_TGTGTGCATG_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:12896
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A5_bach5_TGTGCTCGCA_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:11617
```

And so on. I need to create a .txt file with these numerical grep outputs as columns taking the sample name as a key column. The sample name is the part of the file name before "_R1" (V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A5_bach5_TGTGCTCGCA, V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A4_bach4_TGTGTGCATG...):

```
Sample                                   | Nreads_ini | Nreads_align  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A1_bach1_GTATCGTCGT  | 13175      | 12589         | 
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A2_bach2_GAGTGATCGT  | 14801      | 13934         | 
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A3_bach3_TGAGCGTGCT  | 13475      | 12981         | 
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A4_bach4_TGTGTGCATG  | 13424      | 12896         |
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A5_bach5_TGTGCTCGCA  | 12053      | 11617         |
```

Any idea? Is there another easier solution for my problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answers the variable names are shortened to `ini` and `align`.

First, we extract the sample name and count from grep's output. Since we have to do this multiple times, we define the function

```
e() { sed -E 's,^.*/(.*)_R1.*:(.*)$,\1\t\2,'; }
```

Then we join the extracted data into one file. Lines with the same sample name will be combined.

```
join -t $'\t' <(e <<< "$ini") <(e <<< "$align")
```

Now we nearly have the expected output. We only have to add the header and draw lines for the table.

```
join ... | column -to " | " -N Sample,ini,align
```

This will print

```
Sample                                  | ini   | align
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A1_bach1_GTATCGTCGT | 13175 | 12589
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A2_bach2_GAGTGATCGT | 14801 | 13934
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A3_bach3_TGAGCGTGCT | 13475 | 12981
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A4_bach4_TGTGTGCATG | 13424 | 12896
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A5_bach5_TGTGCTCGCA | 12053 | 11617
```

Adding a horizontal line after the header is left as an exercise for the reader :)

This approach also works with more than two number columns. The `join` and `-N` parts have to be extended. `join` can only work with two files, requiring us to use an unwieldy workaround ...

```
e() { sed -E 's,^.*/(.*)_R1.*:(.*)$,\1\t\2,'; }
join -t $'\t' <(e <<< "$var1") <(e <<< "$var2") |
join -t $'\t' - <(e <<< "$var3") | ... | join -t $'\t' - <(e <<< "$varN") |
column -to " | " -N Sample,Col1,Col2,...,ColN
```

... so it would be easier to add another helper function

```
e() { sed -E 's,^.*/(.*)_R1.*:(.*)$,\1\t\2,'; }
j2() { join -t $'\t' <(e <<< "$1") <(e <<< "$2"); }
j() { join -t $'\t' - <(e <<< "$1"); }
j2 "$var1" "$var2" | j "$var3" | ... | j "$varN" |
column -to " | " -N Sample,Col1,Col2,...,ColN
```

Alternatively, if all inputs contain the same samples in the same order, `join` can be replaced with one single `paste` command.

Comment: Great solution! But what should I do to add more columns based on the other grep expressions (preclust and final)? Seems that join only allows to merge 2 variables.

Comment: @ALG Oh, I forgot that `join` can only handle two files. However, there is a workaround, see my updated answer. I also simplified the header specification.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk --re-interval -F"[/.:]"  '
BEGIN{
  print "Sample                                   | Nreads_ini | Nreads_align  |"
}
FNR==NR{
  match($2,/.*[A-Z]{10}/);
  array[substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)]=$NF;
  next
}
match($2,/.*[A-Z]{10}/) && (substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH) in array){
  print substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH),array[substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)],$NF
}
' OFS=" | "  first_one  second_one | column -t
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Sample                                   |  Nreads_ini  |  Nreads_align  |
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A1_bach1_GTATCGTCGT  |  13175       |  12589
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A2_bach2_GAGTGATCGT  |  14801       |  13934
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A3_bach3_TGAGCGTGCT  |  13475       |  12981
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A4_bach4_TGTGTGCATG  |  13424       |  12896
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A5_bach5_TGTGCTCGCA  |  12053       |  11617
```

Comment: Seems not to work, it's trying to read the file with name PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A1_bach1_GTATCGTCGT_R1.trim.contigs.fasta:13175 (the file name plus the grep count), which does not exist.

Comment: @ALG, with your shown output it gives me same output let me post it in my post now.

Comment: @ALG, looks like output coming from my code is ditto same like shown by you, please do let me know what is not working.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not applying it the correct way. I took the code you posted and simply replaced **first_one** by **$Nreads_ini** and **second_one** by **$Nreads_align**. When executing that, it gives me an error: `awk: cmd. line:3: fatal: cannot open file  (the one mentioned before)`

Comment: @ALG, it is self explanatory that it is not able to find the files. So looks like you are passing shell variables in `awk` code, could you please make sure your shell variables have proper values in them and let me know then?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have files containing the data you want parse:

```
$ cat file1
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A1_bach1_GTATCGTCGT_R1.trim.contigs.fasta:13175
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A2_bach2_GAGTGATCGT_R1.trim.contigs.fasta:14801
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A3_bach3_TGAGCGTGCT_R1.trim.contigs.fasta:13475
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A4_bach4_TGTGTGCATG_R1.trim.contigs.fasta:13424
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A5_bach5_TGTGCTCGCA_R1.trim.contigs.fasta:12053
$ cat file2
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A1_bach1_GTATCGTCGT_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:12589
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A2_bach2_GAGTGATCGT_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:13934
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A3_bach3_TGAGCGTGCT_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:12981
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A4_bach4_TGTGTGCATG_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:12896
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A5_bach5_TGTGCTCGCA_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:11617
$ cat file3 # This is a copy of file2 but could be different
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A1_bach1_GTATCGTCGT_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:12589
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A2_bach2_GAGTGATCGT_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:13934
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A3_bach3_TGAGCGTGCT_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:12981
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A4_bach4_TGTGTGCATG_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:12896
PATH/V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A5_bach5_TGTGCTCGCA_R1.trim.contigs.good.unique.align:11617
```

If there is a key like `V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A1_bach1_GTATCGTCGT`, you could use awk:

```
$ awk -F'[/.:]' '
    BEGINFILE{
      col[FILENAME]
    }
    { 
       row[$2]
       a[FILENAME,$2]=$NF
       next
    }
   END{
      for(i in row) { 
        printf "%s ",substr(i,1,length(i)-3)
        for(j in col) 
          printf "%s ",a[j SUBSEP i]; printf "\n" 
      }
  }' file1 file2 file3
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A4_bach4_TGTGTGCATG 13424 12896 12896
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A1_bach1_GTATCGTCGT 13175 12589 12589
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A3_bach3_TGAGCGTGCT 13475 12981 12981
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A2_bach2_GAGTGATCGT 14801 13934 13934
V3_F357_N_V4_R805_1_A5_bach5_TGTGCTCGCA 12053 11617 11617
```

This awk script fills 3 array `col`, `row` and `a` that respectively stores the column name (filename), the row content and the values for all files.

The `END` statement prints the content of the array `a` by looping through all rows and columns.

If you need table decoration, use this:

```
{ printf "Sample Nreads_ini Nreads_align Nreads_align \n"; awk -F'[/.:]' 'BEGINFILE{col[FILENAME]}{row[$2];a[FILENAME,$2]=$NF;next}END{for(i in row) { printf "%s ",substr(i,1,length(i)-3); for(j in col) printf "%s ",a[j SUBSEP i]; printf "\n" }}' file1 file2 file3; } | column -t  -s' ' -o ' | '
```

Comment: The problem is the for loop. It does not work when using a large amount of files, that is my case.